# How do I create multi-line snippets with quotes, and get them to expand?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I'm setting up Code for html support.

None of the snippet libraries for html support seem to work for me for html snippets, so I'm trying to create my own.

HTML documents create quotes. User snippet definitions for Code require seperate lines to be quoted. I haven't been able to find documentation describing how to handle multiline snippets that contain quotes when defining my own own snippets.

Currently my own snippet is defined as follows, but this doesn't get expanded in the editor:

```
Console log": {
    "prefix": "html5",
    "body": [
        '<html lang="en">'
        '<head>'                                                                                             
     '<meta charset="UTF-8">' 
     '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">'
     '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">'
     '<title></title>'
    '</head>'
    '<body>'

    '</body>'
    '</html>'
],
    "description": "html5 document template"
}
```

How do I get a snippet definition like this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the quotes with a <kbd>\</kbd> (backslash). It would look like this:

```
"html5 document template": {
  "prefix": "html5",
  "body": [
    "<!DOCTYPE html>",
    "<html lang=\"en\">",
    "<head>",
    "  <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">",
    "  <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">",
    "  <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"ie=edge\">",
    "  <title>${1:Document}</title>",
    "</head>",
    "<body>",
    "  ",
    "</body>",
    "</html>"
  ],
  "description": "html5 document template"
}
```

In any HTML document typing "html5" followed by <kbd>⇥</kbd> will expand this snippet.

However, you may not need this one, since [Emmet](https://emmet.io/), which is [included in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) by default, has this one built-in. Type <kbd>!</kbd> followed by <kbd>⇥</kbd> to expand it. There are many more extremely useful abbreviations, you may find [this cheatsheet](https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) useful.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. If I save this and restart VSC, then create a new html file with just 'html5', hitting tab doesn't expand it. Tabs still work for Emmet completions, which is fine, but I want to be able to create my own usable templates anyway.

Comment: It isn't just html completions that aren't working: javascript templates that I create aren't offered for completion in .js files.

Comment: The snippet syntax is definitely correct. Are you putting it in the correct file? Open your command palette with ⌘+⇧+P. Search for and select "Configure User Snippets". Choose "html.json" as the file to add your snippet to and make sure to paste is before the closing } (curly bracket). There is no need restart VS Code after adding new snippets.

Comment: I'm not manually choosing a file to edit. I'm adding the snippets via the file menu, and adding to html.json for html and javascript.json for js.

Comment: Just to make sure that you are editing the correct file, please use the command palette or the menu: Code → Preferences → User Snippets. Your snippet configuration file should look like [this](https://free-picload.com/images/2019/12/26/Screenshot-2019-12-26-at-07.18.21.png), inside a HTML document it should look like [this](https://free-picload.com/images/2019/12/26/Screenshot-2019-12-26-at-07.19.08.png), or alternatively with the Suggestions widget (press CTRL+SPACE) like [this](https://free-picload.com/images/2019/12/26/Screenshot-2019-12-26-at-07.20.39.png).

Comment: I don't have the path 'code'->'preferences'->'user snippets'. What I have is 'file'->'preferences'->'user snippets'. My snippet configuration looks like this: https://pastebin.com/J3Sb3b6j . In an html file, if I begin typing 'html' I am offered the Emmet completions, but not my own template as a suggestion. CTRL+SPACE returns 'no suggestions'.

Comment: I assume your menu looks different because we work on different platforms. As I pointed out previously, you need to add your snippet *BEFORE* the closing bracket of the JSON object. Your file should give the following error in the Problems tab (⇧+⌘+M): `End of file expected. json(0) [16,1]`. In other words, your JSON object is closed in line 15. Paste the snippet before that closing bracket. Your entire configuration file should be *one* JSON object.

Comment: On a related note, you should keep the placeholder I added for the `<title>` tag, see above. It will make using your snippet vastly more convenient. Without it you will have to manually move your cursor there every single time to edit it.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the html.json file and restarted code. The Problems tab shows no issues. However, the completion is still not being offered.

Comment: Did you maybe disable snippets? Do your user or workspace settings contain a setting for `"editor.suggest.showSnippets":`? The default is `true`, so if you don't see it that's fine. Does your language mode say "HTML" on the bottom right of your status bar inside the file where you are trying to use the snippet? Do you get any suggestions at all when typing, regardless of which type?

Comment: @hotpink's snippet is good, so you do have a different issue.

Comment: @hotpink: it's a fresh install and I haven't changed any settings until today. 'editor.suggest.showSnippets' is set to true, and snippets from Emmet are showing. The file I'm editing is an html file, with a .html file suffix. The language mode is HTML.

Comment: Paste the content of your _html.json_ again. The entire file from start to end. Also try adding these settings to your _settings.json_ (can be opened via command palette).
`"editor.tabCompletion": "on"`, `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"`, `"editor.quickSuggestions": {"other": true,"comments": false,"strings": false}`

Comment: @hotpink: html.json: https://hastebin.com/aleyofibiy.php This new combination of settings does create a change: a html5-boilerplate snippet I installed from a package now gets suggested and can be completed. But my own custom snippet doesn't get suggested.

Comment: Your snippets file looks good. Maybe disable all extensions via the command palette and try again. I'm afraid this is the end of the line for me. I have no idea what else to suggest. Good luck!

Comment: Is There, a way that not writing the "", every line?

Comment: no, JSON always requires strings to be wrapped in double quotes